# Calculating RAM memory capacity from schematic symbol

Tags: memory, ram, ddr

Is it possible to calculate the memory capacity of a RAM given its schematic symbol?

I made a first guess from an example but seems to be incorrect:

[image]

If the address bus is 15-bit width, there are a total amount of 2^15 = 32768 addresses

If the data bus is 16-bit width, there are two bytes per address

Then, the total amount of bytes would be 32768 x 2 = 65536 = 65 kilobytes

However, the [manufacturer states](https://www.micron.com/products/dram/ddr3-sdram/part-catalog/mt41k128m16jt-125-xit) that its capacity is 2 Gigabit = 256 Megabytes

So my first guess is incorrect. How can the capacity be calculated given the schematic symbol?

Comment: How about checking the part's datasheet? You have the PN on the schematic. You are missing several aspects of it - such as different address banks

Comment: You can't, any more than you could calculate a transistors maximum voltage or current ratings from it's schematic symbol. Suppose it had a serial interface?

Comment: Through knowing how DRAM works, which is described in the datasheet, and which bits of the address bus are multiplexed between Row and Column addresses (and which are not), also from datasheet, and understanding the role of the BA (Bank Address) bits.   Or, more simply, by dissecting the part number, and multiplying 128M by 16.

Comment: You can't. These SDRAM devices latch Row & Column addresses separately, both from the common address bus, using RAS# and CAS#. The datasheet will tell you how many address bits are used for Rows & how many are used for Columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it *cannot* be calculated from the schematic symbol alone, but only by reading the data sheet corresponding to the *part number* in that symbol.

You example is a perfect demonstration of why - modern chips used multi-phased addressing, and you have to understand exactly how addressing works before you could know the capacity.

Read the data sheet for the indicated part, and you will see how it achieves this capacity by loading only part of the address at any given instant in time.

Then there's the whole history going nearly back to the dawn of computing of boards that could be populated by different capacity chips having compatible pinouts...

Answer (score 1):

That’s a DRAM with a multiplexed address bus (row, column) and multiple banks (8 - from the three BAx bits).

You’ll need to consult the datasheet based on the part number, which you’ve done, to determine its capacity. This is because there are more row bits than column ones, so without a ‘peek inside’ at the DRAM architecture you don’t really know the total number of address bits in use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. The part number has "128M16" in it and it says it is DDR3 memory. From this alone, it can be assumed to have 128M addresses, each address containing 16 bits of data, equalling the said 256 megabytes or 8 gigabits of memory.